# Default behavior remains after app uninstall

Tags: default-applications

I have a problem with the Wikipedia app. After I installed it, links in the Google Search result page link to the Wikipedia app, which is the expected behavior.

After I uninstalled the app I thought that the links would open in my browser again. But, unhappily, now links to Wikipedia in the search result pages opens the Google Play Store with the Wikipedia app entry.

Is there a reason why the deeplinking isn't removed after the app is uninstalled?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable redirects from Google Search results to Android apps?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/83319/how-to-disable-redirects-from-google-search-results-to-android-apps)

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. I tested it with the latest chrome, but i haven't cleared the stored data for *wikipedia.org. I will test it later, but i have the same problem with HTC/Android stock browser and i don't know, if there is the same setting. I will check and give feedback.

Comment: Its not the same :/ the problem is the same in chrome and htc stock browser. And only, if you're logged in with the google account with which you installed the wikipedia app. If you're logged out, the browser normally redirects to *m.wikipedia.org, so i think its not a device problem :(